# HTML: Is there a way to allow the user to type in their input but also have a drop down select menu?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, user-input, html-select

For example, I have

```
 <label class="form">Menu</label>
      <select id="selection" name="select" required>
           <option value="" selected>--Select an Option--</option>
           <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
           <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
           ...
      </select>
```

This would only give a a drop down menu when the user clicks on the input box with their mouse.  But I want to give them the option to be able to type in the input box such as:

If the user types in `option1` it would direct them to the "Option 1" drop-down menu, etc.  And if the user types in any other words that are not included in the drop-down list it would show "Invalid Input".

Comment: This is called a “combo box.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is! A text input with a list attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="city" list="cityname">
<datalist id="cityname">
  <option value="Boston">
  <option value="Cambridge">
</datalist>
```

EDIT: for the autocomplete, try [Bootstrap Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

Comment: Thanks, I was using the <select> tag but this works so much better.

Comment: Apologoes Ryan, this answer might be outdated now - it's coming up 5 years old!